Example of draggable = 'true' property of dash html.Button element?
I am trying to find an example of the "draggable" property being set to "true" for the html.Button element (https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/button) in dash core components.
In the above documentation, it clearly states that this property determines whether the button is draggable or not. However, using this code:
from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('accounts.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Br(),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-row-ids',
        columns=[
            {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df.columns
            # omit the id column
            if i != 'id'
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode='multi',
        row_selectable='multi',
        row_deletable=True,
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action='native',
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 10,
    ),
    html.Div(id='datatable-row-ids-container'),
    html.Button('Hello', draggable='true')
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

The button is clearly not draggable:
enter image description here
when I click and hold the "Hello" button, nothing happens.
I tried the above code, and i expected the "Hello" button to be draggable (i.e., to move position on the page when one clicks and holds on the button). However nothing happened to the button
Does anyone know how the "draggable" property works ?
Or are there any examples of it being used ?
Thank you
